# Call function when view is fully updated in Angular2

Tags: angular

My application will show a list of messages (with scroll). When the user add a new message, the page need to scroll to the bottom of the messages-list. Is it correct to call scrollToBottom() immediately after the new message is added to the messages list? Or will it give timing issues? Will the view already been updated (contain the new message) so scrollHeight will be correct? Or other way to formulate my question: is there a way to know / be sure that the view is fully updated when the model changed.

View (messaging.html):

```html
<div class=”height: 100%; scroll: auto”>
  <div class="message" *ngFor="#message of messages">
    ...
  </div>
</div
```

Component:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'messaging',
  templateUrl: './messaging.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messaging.css'],
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class Messaging {
  private messages:Message[] = [];

  @ViewChild('messagingscroll') private messageScroll: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
  }

  sendMessage(message:string, element) {
    let msg:Message = new Message(message);

    // Add msg
    this.messages.push(msg);

    // Scroll to bottom
    this.scrollToBottom();

    // Set back empty
    element.value = '';
  }

  scrollToBottom(): void {
    this.messageScroll.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.messageScroll.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call function when your view is fully load than you can call default life cycle hook of angular2 i.e `ngAfterViewinit()`

see here for more info https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/AfterViewInit-interface.html

according to officials

> Implement this interface to get notified when your component's view has been fully initialized.

as you need you have to call function every time after view changes so ,you can use `ngAfterViewchecked`.

> Implement this interface to get notified after every check of your component's view.

see more here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/AfterViewChecked-interface.html

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() will only be called at start-up / initialization. So not after I add a new message.
But with your answer I found, ngAfterViewChecked, I think this is maybe the solution?

Comment: yeah there are few life cycle for view you can check here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html